# How to set a proxy for terminal without exporting the environment variable?

Tags: proxy, http, terminal, environment-variables

How to set a proxy for terminal without exporting the environment variable?

I am using a Ubuntu machine and I would like to do that?

If it not possible, are there any apps to help me do that?

Thank you.

Comment: be more precise, you have two options, either using iptables or using a default configuration. it's missing what you want to afford

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always set up the variable just for the command you want to run, for instance, you can do the following:

```
$ HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128 curl https://external.domain.com/
```

And curl will use the HTTPS_PROXY defined right there and only once.

If you want to set the environment variable, it will work for the whole Terminal Session, but not for any other user/system - it won't affect your cron jobs, for instance.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer and I am very thankful.

Comment: This doesn't work on macOS terminal though..

Comment: Are you using the default zsh? that's just a lame shel IMHO, change the default to bash.